# Reducing wattage

Tags: amplifier

I have a 400 watt speaker cabinet that I would like to run with a 700 watt amp.  Is there something I can make or a way to reduce the amp output wattage so I don't tear out my speakers - without just turning the volume down?

Comment: What kind of amp or speaker? Standard home theatre or some PA gear for a garage band? Because normal listening levels should not require more than few watts.

Comment: What's wrong with just turning the volume down?

Comment: Use a compressor/limiter on the input side of the amplifier, which pretty much amounts to the same thing as turning the volume down.

Comment: @Transistor He might turn it up accidentally and break the speakers.

Comment: You'll hear distortion before the speakers blow. That's your prompt to turn it down.

Answer (score 1):

First check if the "700W" amplifier rating is musical watts, RMS watts, or other sort of watts. If it is "700 RMS watts per channel" (which in audio lingo means "real watts") then the amp is actually capable of outputting that power. If it's musical watts or any other kind of marketing watts (or worse, PMPO) then it is not. The same applies to the speakers, if they are rated for 400 "musical watts" or other kinds of "marketing watts" these are not real watts.

Now if it is rated to 700 "RMS watts" it won't output that power all the time. It will do so only if you crank up the volume to the max, close to clipping. So, for example you could play a full scale 50Hz sine wave with speakers disconnected, then measure the AC RMS output voltage of the amp with a multimeter or a scope. I'm suggesting 50 Hz because most multimeters that aren't too expensive are more accurate in AC mode at not too high frequency.

700W into 8 ohms is 105V peak, or 75V RMS.

350W into 8 ohms is 75V peak, or 53V RMS.

So, playing a full scale sine wave, with all the relevant pots set to max level on the mixing desk, you can adjust the amp's volume pot to make sure that it will never output more than 53V RMS, or 350W, no matter what the settings are on the source or mixing desk.

Note that the power rating of speakers isn't very accurate. Most speakers will probably tolerate double their power rating for a while (like minutes) before they overheat and burn. However at some frequency which depends on the speaker, your woofer will bottom out and destroy itself with a lot less than its rated power. But in this case it sounds like it's going to explode, so you have a warning.

If this is for a living room hifi application and not a PA application, then I wouldn't even bother to look into it. You're going to use less than a watt most of the times anyway. 10W with speakers of decent efficiency is already deafeningly loud. You will go deaf before the speaker breaks a sweat.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if it's a stereo amp, it might be 350W per channel.  Problem solved.

Otherwise, check the speaker impedance on the amp spec.  It should say something like "700W into 8 ohms."  If that's the case, use 16 ohm speakers and you're down to 350W.  For all I know, you may already be inadvertently doing this.

If choosing other speakers isn't an option, you could drop the voltage using an audio transformer.  A 1.41:1 turns ratio should halve your output power.

If all else fails, you could add a series resistor about half the resistance value of your speaker and connect it in series.  It will have to dissipate ~200W in the worst case, though, so make sure it's a big one, and mounted someplace where it won't burn your speaker cabinet or curious children's/pet's fingers.

Comment: Adding a series resistor, as far as I know, ruins the damping of the speaker as it is no longer controlled by the low output impedance of the amplifier. You've created an R-L circuit.

Comment: @Transistor That's just one of the reasons I listed it last.  However, in most conventional moving-cone speakers, the speaker impedance is largely resistive, and a series resistor with half the resistance of the speaker won't make *much* difference (although more than none).